# How to execute a query which is stored in a table column MySQL?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, group-concat, sql-server-group-concat

```
mysql> select * from CT;

| CID | MID | REPORT_QUERY           |
|   1 |   1 | select * from emp;     |
|   2 |   2 | select * from student; |

2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I want to execute queries in `REPORT_QUERY` column.

```
DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE TRYct()
   BEGIN
SET @str=(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(REPORT_QUERY SEPARATOR ' ') FROM CT);
PREPARE q from @str;
EXECUTE q;
   END //
 DELIMITER ;
```

i use this code but it works if there is only one query in my table. if there is two query than it gives an error.

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select * from student' at line 1
```

where is the problem ? Help me.

Comment: I'm not a fan of storing sql in sql tables, but it seems odd to me that you are trying to run such queries from a sql stored proc. If you're keeping it in sql, why not just make stored procs directly; and if not, why not just run the queries from the client side?

Answer (score 8):

You can use a cursor to get each `REPORT_QUERY` on `CT` table, and execute that using prepared statements:

```
delimiter $$
drop procedure if exists run_queries$$
create procedure run_queries()
begin

    declare s_query varchar(255);

    declare done bool default false;
    declare c_queries cursor for    
        select REPORT_QUERY from CT;
    declare continue handler for not found set done = true;


    open c_queries;
    read_loop: loop

        fetch c_queries into s_query;
        if done then 
            leave read_loop;
        end if;

        -- run the query
        set @sql = s_query;
        prepare stmt from  @sql;
        execute stmt;
        deallocate prepare stmt;
    end loop;

end$$
```

After create procedure, you can call as bellow:

call run_queries();

That's it.

Comment: @Shoaeb in that case we can use another type like `text` or  just increase the size to 1024.... I don't know

Answer (score 4):

If you want to execute SQL that is stored in column of some MySQL table, try this:

```
SELECT sql_text INTO @sql FROM sql_queries WHERE id = 1;
PREPARE sql_query FROM @sql;
EXECUTE sql_query;
```

Contents of the table `sql_queries`:

```
+----+--------------------------+
| id |         sql_text         |
+----+--------------------------+
|  1 | select * from companies; |
+----+--------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

As i understand your question is that you need to run the queries which are stored in table column in `SQL` Form.

Here you can fetch the queries form `table column` and execute them in mysqli.

SQL QUERY TABLE IMAGE HERE THE QUERIES ARE STORED [image: QUERY TABLE IMAGE]

SQL EMPLOYEE TABLE [WHICH IS DYNAMICALLY CALLED BY QUERY TABLE DURING EXECUTION]

[image: employees table]

PHP SQL CODE : `

```
<?php
    $link = new mysqli ('localhost','root','admin','demo');

    if($link->connect_error){
        die ("Connection Failed".$link->connect_error);
    }

    //YOU NEED THIS AS YOU NEED TO ACCESS THE COLUMN DATA IN TABLE
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM querytable WHERE id=1";

    if($res = $link->query($sql)){
        //IF THE ROW EXISTS
        if($res->num_rows > 0){
            while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){

                $query = $row['report_query']; //HERE IS THE SQL QUERY STORED IN TABLE , WHICH IS STORED IN ANOTHER VARIABLE
                $result = $link->query($query); // NOW EXECUTE THE QUERY
                if($result->num_rows > 0){
            ?>
                    <table border="1" cellpadding="10">
                        <tr>
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                        </tr>
            <?php
                    while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                        //DISPLAY RESULTS HERE
            ?>          
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $rows['first_name'];?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $rows['lastname'];?></td>
                        </tr>
            <?php
                    }
            ?>
                    </table>
        <?php
                }
            }
        }   
    }
    else
    {
        echo $link->error;
    }
?>
```

`